# Is it possible to determine which Entity a Poco maps to, using code, for Entity Framework CTP5?

Tags: entity-framework, metadata, poco, entity-framework-ctp5

I'm not sure how I can get the `EntityFramework` meta-data for an `Entity` (i have on my EF designer / edmx) for a `Poco` object.

For example.

My diagram has an Entity called `User`. I also have a Poco class called `User`. I'm under the impression that the Entity name and Poco need to be the same name, so the convention can auto-map the two (along with the poco having the same property names, etc...)

So if i have a type Poco, how can i retrieve the Entity and therefore check that entity to see it's meta-data, like `EntityKey` or `StoreGeneratedPattern`, etc ?

Oh - by the way... I don't know what the Poco type is .. meaning .. the class uses Generics...

```
public class GenericRepository<T> : IRepository<T> where T : class
{ ... }
```

So, i thought i was going to have to ask the context ... grab me the entity which has a `name == typeof(T).Name` or whatever...

Answer (score 1):

Access to mapping metadata is normally performed by `ObjectContext.MetadataWorkspace`. CTP5 hides `ObjectContext` instance and most of its mapping classes related to mapping (based on `DbMappingMetadataItem`) are internal or contains only internal members.

It looks like your `DbContext` is autogenerated from EDMX. What you can probably do it this case is create `DbContext` by calling constructor which accepts `ObjectCotnext`. In that case you will have access to `ObjectContext` and all its methods / properties.

Why do you need it? If you need something special to do in your repository you should create special repository for that type. Generic repository is concept only for very basic solutions.

Comment: because i've got a generic repo, I'm trying to find the poco's equivalent Entity, which i created on the designer. If i can find the equivalent Entity on the designer/MetData, then find which property on that Entity is the first EntityKey AND StoreGeneratedPattern == Identity, then I can do some custom stuff. Right now, i'm using a Convention right now to find that property.. so I was hoping to use the Entity Designer/Metadata instead of convention.

Comment: In such case you should simply model all your entities to contain single key with the same type and the same name. Then you will define interface which will demand property with the same name and implement this interface in all your enitites. Your generic repository can then use restriction for generic type to be implementing the interface and you will have direct access to property.

Comment: I didn't want to have to have my poco's impliment an interface which is used for persistence. To me, that's some persistent code smell on a poco .. when a poco shouldn't care about persistence in _any_ way. Currently, i'm using a Convention -> find the first property that ends with 'Id' and that's the Identity. Or u can define the name of the property upon construction (which DI/IoC handles). But this is still not nice, IMO. Works - sure. I was hoping to use the properties of the EF MetaData .. which is 100% way more accurate. Thoughts?

Comment: @Pure.Krome: No. I will think about it.

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to the ObjectContext (which I think you MUST have, since EntityKey/EntityState wouldn't make sense without the context), you can use the following

```
ObjectStateEntry ose = 
    context.ObjectStateManager.GetObjectStateEntry(yourObject);
```

From there, you can get all sorts of fun properties:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.objects.objectstateentry.aspx

You may also find `TryGetObjectStateEntry(...)` to be handy.

Comment: heya :) hmm. i definately have access to the Context (which is a DbContext) .. but there's no ObjectStateManager property, on that context? has it be renamed in CTP5?

Comment: Also .. what happens if i don't have any entities in memory? can i still grab the structure and query for properties against that?

Comment: Since you're using a DbContext, you can say ((IObjectContextAdapter)context).ObjectContext